# Convert topocentric coordinates (Azimuth, Elevation) to equatorial coordinates (RA, Dec) with PyEphem

Tags: python, coordinate-systems, astronomy, pyephem

This looks quite a basic task, but I cannot sort it out.

The PyEphem documentation:

http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/radec.html

describes how to perform the conversion the other way around, from a `Body` and an `Observer` objects to Apparent Topocentric Position, with elevation and azimuth in the `.alt` and `.az` attributes.

However how should I, instead, start from Elevation and Azimuth and get RA and Dec?

For example here is one set of coordinates for which I'd like to get RA and Dec in Equatorial reference frame:

```
az = 3.30084818 #rad
el = 0.94610742 #rad
lat = 34.64 #deg
lon = -103.7 #deg
alt = 35800.26 #m
ut = 2455822.20000367 #julian date
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two subtleties here. First, you have happened to use “elevation” and “altitude” to mean the opposite of what the two terms mean in the PyEphem library — so you are calling the spot in the sky its “elevation / azimuth" position instead of its “altitude / azimuth” position. Second, it appears that PyEphem has forgotten to provide an easy way to convert dates *from* Julian *to* its own format. While there is a function `julian_date()` that will go the other direction, we will have to do a bit of work ourselves to go the other direction by figuring out what `ephem`'s name is for.

With those stipulations in mind, I think this script might answer your question:

```
import ephem

az = 3.30084818 #rad
el = 0.94610742 #rad
lat = 34.64 #deg
lon = -103.7 #deg
alt = 35800.26 #m
ut = 2455822.20000367 #julian date

# Which Julian Date does Ephem start its own count at?
J0 = ephem.julian_date(0)

observer = ephem.Observer()
observer.lon = str(lon)  # str() forces deg -> rad conversion
observer.lat = str(lat)  # deg -> rad
observer.elevation = alt
observer.date = ut - J0

print observer.date
print observer.radec_of(az, el)
```

Does the answer it produces look correct for this particular observation? Here is what the script prints for me:

```
2011/9/17 16:48:00
(9:16:24.95, -0:45:56.8)
```

Let me know if that makes physical sense for this particular observation, or if one of the numbers is wrong here and still needs to be tweaked!

Comment: Thanks Brandon, it works great, here I have an example comparing to JPL horizon results: https://gist.github.com/1672906

Comment: I wonder why the answers do not agree to greater precision? I might have to look into that! Where did you get those two numbers — from a form on the JPL web site?

Comment: yes, on JPL Horizon website, I wonder that maybe Horizon is including other corrections as well.